# Error : Failed dependencies rpm

Tags: centos, package-management, virtualbox

When I tried to install an rpm in my CentOS7.8 virtual box with this command:

```
rpm -ivh cpp-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64.rpm kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-headers-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-devel-2.17-317.el7.i686.rpm glibc-devel-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I got this error.

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        glibc = 2.17-317.el7 is needed by glibc-headers-2.17-317.el7.x86_64
        glibc = 2.17-317.el7 is needed by glibc-devel-2.17-317.el7.i686
        glibc = 2.17-317.el7 is needed by glibc-devel-2.17-317.el7.x86_64
```

Can anyone tell me what it means and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You use `yum/dnf` for that. Looks like you've fetched some packages somewhere but your base system is not up to date.

(As a quick workaround, download glibc-2.17-317.el7.i686.rpm and glibc-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm as well, and first `rpm -Uvh` to them).